# convert an x-www-form-urlencoded string to JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

Exampple of application/x-www-form-urlencoded string

incoming request looks like this

```
type=update&date_time=2022-08-29T11%3A08%3A36-05%3A00&initiated_from=admin&initiated_by=admin&list=0&contact%5Bid%5D=271&contact%5Bemail%5D=btgctest8291%40gmail.com&contact%5Bfirst_name%5D=btgctest8291&contact%5Blast_name%5D=testlad&contact%5Bphone%5D=8291000000&contact%5Bip%5D=0.0.0.0&contact%5Btags%5D=test-automation-tag&contact%5Bcustomer_acct_name%5D=&contact%5Borgname%5D=&customer_acct_name=&customer_acct_id=0&orgname=
```

Into JSON

```
{
  "type":"update",
  "contact":{
    "id":"55",
    "email":"Ada67@yahoo.com",
    "first_name":"Frankus",
    "last_name":"Bechte",
    "phone":""
  }
}
```

**querystring** returns

```
{
  type: 'update',
  'contact[id]': '271',
  'contact[email]': 'btgctest8291@gmail.com',
  'contact[first_name]': 'btgctest8291',
  'contact[last_name]': 'testlad',
  'contact[phone]': '8291000000',
  'contact[ip]': '0.0.0.0',
  'contact[tags]': 'test-automation-tag',
  'contact[customer_acct_name]': '',
  'contact[orgname]': ''
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just transform this object like this:

```js
const string = 'type=update&date_time=2022-08-29T11%3A08%3A36-05%3A00&initiated_from=admin&initiated_by=admin&list=0&contact%5Bid%5D=271&contact%5Bemail%5D=btgctest8291%40gmail.com&contact%5Bfirst_name%5D=btgctest8291&contact%5Blast_name%5D=testlad&contact%5Bphone%5D=8291000000&contact%5Bip%5D=0.0.0.0&contact%5Btags%5D=test-automation-tag&contact%5Bcustomer_acct_name%5D=&contact%5Borgname%5D=&customer_acct_name=&customer_acct_id=0&orgname='
const params = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams('type=update&date_time=2022-08-29T11%3A08%3A36-05%3A00&initiated_from=admin&initiated_by=admin&list=0&contact%5Bid%5D=271&contact%5Bemail%5D=btgctest8291%40gmail.com&contact%5Bfirst_name%5D=btgctest8291&contact%5Blast_name%5D=testlad&contact%5Bphone%5D=8291000000&contact%5Bip%5D=0.0.0.0&contact%5Btags%5D=test-automation-tag&contact%5Bcustomer_acct_name%5D=&contact%5Borgname%5D=&customer_acct_name=&customer_acct_id=0&orgname='))

const data = {
  type: 'update',
  'contact[id]': '271',
  'contact[email]': 'btgctest8291@gmail.com',
  'contact[first_name]': 'btgctest8291',
  'contact[last_name]': 'testlad',
  'contact[phone]': '8291000000',
  'contact[ip]': '0.0.0.0',
  'contact[tags]': 'test-automation-tag',
  'contact[customer_acct_name]': '',
  'contact[orgname]': ''
}

const json = Object.entries(data).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
  const [name, sub] = key.match(/[^\[\]]+/g)
  if (!sub) {
    obj[name] = value
  } else if (obj[name]) {
    obj[name][sub] = value
  } else {
    obj[name] = {}
  }
  return obj
}, {})

console.log(json)
```